# .htaccess ?pages mask

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have done a full search but cant seem to find exactly what im after (sorry if I have missed it).

Basically I only want to make ONE $_GET value, the ?pages value.

So I want this:

```
localhost/?page=login
```

to become

```
localhost/login
```

but I want to be able to use other $_GET values without them being hidden, for example, I need this to work

```
localhost/login?id=12 or localhost/login?name=dave
```

I also need all the url requests to go through the single index.php file.

Any help would be really appreciated. Cant seem to get quite what im after.

Thank you

Comment: You are looking for mod_rewrites `QSA` flag. Take a look at the excellent documentation!

Answer (score 0):

> So I want this:
>
> ```
> localhost/?page=login
> ```
>
> to become
>
> ```
> localhost/login
> ```

Actually, this is not quite correct. What you want is

```
/login
```

to become

```
/index.php?page=login
```

This can be done using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

The [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag causes the original query string and the new query string (`page=$1`) to be combined, instead of discarding the original query string.

To disable rewriting URLs that point to an existing file name or directory, add appropriate [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)-directives, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

before the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Okay sorry im new to the .htaccess business. Thank you. so how do you get everything to go through the index.php file?

Comment: By applying the `RewriteRule` I gave in the answer.

Comment: ah okay, I see why what I have isnt working. I have a directory login as well. Is there a way to disregard any directory with the same value as ?pages?

Comment: BTW: this has nothing to do with `.htaccess` (except for the fact that such [Apache configuration directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html)) are often placed in the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: thank you good to know. Do you have a solution to: "I see why what I have isnt working. I have a directory login as well. Is there a way to disregard any directory with the same value as ?pages"

Comment: Thank you for that. Something is still not quite right:
http://localhost/login/?id=test&name=dave
gives me
Array ( [page] => login/index.php [name] => dave )
as you can see the id is not being picked up and the value for ?pages should be login not login/index.php. Thank you

Comment: any one got any idea why only the ?id wont work? any other key and it is fine